# Google Places Autocomplete: Format displayed result after selecting one (just display streetname + number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm desperately trying to set the input value of googles autocomplete, after the user selected an address, to just the selected "streetname number", insteat of "streetname number, city, country".

Its possible to set the value after the user hits enter, but whenever the autocomplete input field looses focus, the value jumps back to the suggested (too long) string.

There must be an easy trick to do this, but I'm out of ideas..

Anybody had this problem or knows a solution?

Comment: Can you post an example so I can take a look.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but we were able to find a solution, see answer below, but still thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer, but I was able to fix it by using some jquery.

```
$("#autocomplete_input_display_just_streetname").focusout(function () {
  document.getElementById("autocomplete_input_display_just_streetname").value = "currentPlace.name;";
});
```